# Error:(1, 41) Kotlin: Symbol is declared in module 'jdk.internal.opt' which does not export package 'jdk.i

Tags: kotlin

I have a beginner problem. 
Just installed IntellijIDEA and JDK (Java Development Kit) and can't build my project.

Code:

```
import jdk.internal.joptsimple.internal.Strings

fun main(args: Array<Strings>){println("Hello")}
```

Error:

```
Error:(1, 41) Kotlin: Symbol is declared in module 'jdk.internal.opt' which does not export package 'jdk.internal.joptsimple.internal'
```

Comment: it is Array of strings  Array< Strings >

Comment: Why do you need this package? It's internal JDK package and you should not use it without real need. You already have String class accessible from everywhere, so you can just remove this import

Comment: You just have a typo: `Strings` instead of `String`. Then you likely had IntelliJ auto-import the aforementioned `Strings` class. Just fix the typo and remove the import.

Answer (score 2):

The proper `main` function with arguments looks like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

}
```

Note that `args` is an array of Kotlin's `String` not `jdk.internal.joptsimple.internal.Strings`. So just fix your method's signature and remove the import statement.